# Can email address be used as user name?

Tags: user-registration

Is it possible to do something to WP so that I'm able to use the e-mail address as username?

I do not want to download a plugin for this.

Comment: I'm not sure if the WP's user registration page allows it, but the wp_insert_user_() function certainly does... I did this for a newsletter registration system, where each subscriber has the email assigned as name

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this, all you have to do is create a user registration page and have the email address field fill both the username and email args to use for the wp_insert_user() function.

Comment: Any chance of WP misbehaving when doing this?

Answer (score -1):

WordPress uses the following function when creating users:

sanitize_user()

```
Sanitize username stripping out unsafe characters.

If $strict is true, only alphanumeric characters plus these: _, space, ., -, *, and @ are returned.

Removes tags, octets, entities, and if strict is enabled, will remove all non-ASCII characters. After sanitizing, it passes the username, raw username (the username in the parameter), and the strict parameter as parameters for the filter.
```

Short answer: Not without a plugin.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_user

Comment: can't I create my own username sanitazion in functions.php that overrides the one WP is using by deafult?

Comment: You're going to do it within a theme or edit the default functions.php?